# How Can I Get a List of Every Command in an R Package?

Tags: r, package

I want to see a list of the available commands in an R package, ideally, outputted to the console. In RStudio, I can type the name of a package, followed by two colons (e.g. `ggplot2::`) and RStudio's GUI will pop up a list of available commands. Is this such a list? Even so, I can't get that to output to the console, and it doesn't work in vanilla R. Any alternatives?

Comment: BTW,  you can get that output in the R GUI by typing ggplot:: and then typing <TAB> for completion.

Comment: They're not commands, they are exported objects. They could be functions or data.

Comment: @G5W Nice tip! Although, it does truncate the results. Perhaps there's a way to modify the settings so it doesn't.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the clarification. I sometimes get confused about the R lingo. When learning other programming languages, my instructors always called them 'commands'. I see that they can be functions or data, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> require(ggplot2)
```

Then

```
> ls("package:ggplot2")
  [1] "%+%"                       "aes"                      
  [3] "aes_"                      "aes_all"                  
  [5] "aes_auto"                  "aes_q"                    
  [7] "aes_string"                "alpha"                    
  [9] "annotate"                  "annotation_custom"
  [etc]
```

You can also use `ls()` with a position on the search list, eg

```
> ls(pos=2)
```

Get the search list with `search()`.

Answer (score 2):

This gets all the functions in particular package. Here's all the functions in tidyr:

```
objs <- mget(ls("package:tidyr"), inherits = TRUE)
funs <- Filter(is.function, objs)
```

Comment: Do you want to apply `names()` to `funs`?

Comment: If you want just the names, sure!

Comment: This is a really neat solution because, as @G5W noted, you can wrap the `funs` object in `names()` to just get the names, but if you want to see the guts of each function individually, you can just return `funs`.